# perform segue from pageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, uipageviewcontroller

My problem is as follows: I am using pageViewControllers to create a tutorial/onboarding page for an app i'm creating.  A left swipe gesture on the last (3rd) page of my tutorial should perform a segue.

This is what I have as of now, but it is giving me a key value coding-compliancy error. I have double, triple checked my outlets, and `swipeView` is very much so connected properly.

```
class GrowController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var swipeView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(swipeView)
    createGesture()

}

func createGesture() {
    let showReg = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showRegister))
    showReg.direction = .left
    self.swipeView.addGestureRecognizer(showReg)
}

func showRegister(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showRegister", sender: self)
  }
}
```

That is the controller for the actual `UIViewController` (the specific page that is being displayed)

now ive also tried messing around with some logic in my `TutorialViewController` which is the `UIPageViewController` controlling the swipes form page to page etc.

Logic for that here

```
class TutorialViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var viewControllerIndex: Int?

//Array of my pages to load (GrowController is page3)
lazy var tutorialArray: [UIViewController] = {
    return [self.tutorialInstance(name: "page1"), self.tutorialInstance(name: "page2"), self.tutorialInstance(name: "page3")]
}()

private func tutorialInstance(name: String?) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name!)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self

    if let firstViewController = tutorialArray.first {
        setViewControllers([firstViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}

// Scroll view
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds 
        }
        else if view is UIPageControl {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}


// Page View Controller delegate functions
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = tutorialArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return nil
    }

    guard tutorialArray.count > previousIndex else {
// Added this line just testing around, nothing happened here though.
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowRegister", sender: self)
        return nil
    }

    return tutorialArray[previousIndex]
}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewControllerIndex = tutorialArray.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

    guard nextIndex < tutorialArray.count else {
        return nil
    }

    guard tutorialArray.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return tutorialArray[nextIndex]
}

public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return tutorialArray.count
}

public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first, let firstViewControllerIndex = tutorialArray.index(of: firstViewController) else {
        return 0
    }
    return firstViewControllerIndex
    }


}
```

Does is have something to do with the `willTransitionTo` `pageView` delegate method? I'm not familiar how to implement that, I have tried.

I thought that i could just add a subView to the Grow controller, put a swipe gesture in it, and perform a segue whenever the user swipes left from that page. As of right now, this code crashes the app upon loading of page3 (`GrowController`)

Any help GREATLY appreciated, I've been trying to figure this out for over a week and this is the second question on the topic i've posed. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Let me just check that I understand what you want to do. You want the user to be able to swipe-swipe-swipe to get thru the three pages of the page view controller, and then if the user goes swipe again, we segue right out of here? Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly! except that it starts on page one, and its just swipe-swipe, and then the third swipe from page3 will segue out! but yes thats the exact concept

Comment: Are the segues properly attached from the GrowController to the next controller? (via storyboard or programmatically).  Also, could you post the actual error logs that you get.

Comment: mark, yes the segues are properly connected and above is now an image of my actual error log - I have never seen/set `speed` or `speedVariance`, and cannot find either written anywhere programatically in any code -.-

Will try the answer below now matt!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a UIPageViewController for this. That's very ironic, because I am usually the first to advise using UIPageViewController. But in this case it is doing too much of the work for you, and you cannot interfere in such a way as to customize it the way you're describing. You will need to use a simple paging UIScrollView; that way, you will be *totally* in charge of what happens, with fine-grained response thanks to the scroll view's delegate, and you'll have access to the underlying pan gesture recognizer and can modify its behavior.